# Windows Store Apps: Globalizing Grid View Item Template

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have an app that supports two languages: English and Arabic.

In a page I have a GridView, and I have two Item Templates for the GridView; one for English and one for Arabic.

how to handle the switching of item templates according to the current language of the app efficiently ?

Comment: Have you tried [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the language tag of the app's preferred language:

`Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.primaryLanguageOverride`

and use it with a `DataTemplateSelector` to choose the right `ItemTemplate`.

Something like this:

```
public class LanguageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{ 
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate2 { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.primaryLanguageOverride;

        if(language.Equals("LanguageTAG"))
        {
             return ItemTemplate1;
        }
        else if(language.Equals("AnotherLanguageTAG"))
        {
            return ItemTemplate2;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that's the best way